# Python function in imported file cannot access another function in the calling Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter notebook with python version 3.6. I have some code written in a separate external.py file that I import, then call a function from this file. This function then calls a function defined in the body of the python notebook. For instance,

```
import external
def subsequent():
    <some code>
external.func1()
```

func1 is called successfully but gives error when calling 'subsequent', from within func1. 
I have tried moving the 'import external' line to be after the definition of 'subsequent'. This did not work either.

Is there a way to reference the calling ipython notebook?

Many thanks

Regards,

Adeel

Comment: Does func1() calls subsequent() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try lambda function and pass that function as a parameter to func1.

```
  from external import func1
  subsequent=lambda a : print(a + 10)
  func1(subsequent)
```

OR

pass the function as a parameter

```
from external import func1
def subsequent(a):
    print(a + 10)
func1(subsequent)
```

Cheers :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dulmina. Worked like a charm!